# How to get a visa to Iran as a US Citizen?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, iran

I am a us citizen I want to travel to Iran in 3 months to meet up with someone I have been talking to for sometime. we both thought it would be nice to finally meet. I also want to see the beautiful places that she has told me about. so I would like to know how would I go about getting the visa and how much would it cost

Comment: It's extremely difficult for an American to go to Iran. It's even become difficult to go to Kish Island. Consider meeting in a third country.

Comment: This sounds like a wonderfully bad idea.  From the U.S. State Department:  Do not travel to Iran due to the risk of kidnapping and the arbitrary arrest and detention of U.S. citizens.  For more details see 
 https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/iran-travel-advisory.html

Answer (score 5):

It's a stunning country, but does present problems for some of us with stamps from there in our passport, especially trying to visit the US.... ;) But I digress...

For a while it was nearly impossible, but visas are indeed available for US Citizens, however, not on arrival.  Now you can get a visa, but you must be part of an official organised tour.

For a full guide, have a read of [Intrepid's guide on the matter](https://www.intrepidtravel.com/adventures/travel-iran-usa-citizens/).

Fees vary depending on your citizenship, how urgently you need it etc, but would suggest applying 60-90 days in advance, it can take time...

Comment: Note for the OP: The Intrepid guide cited in Mark's post indicates that for US citizens, there is apparently no independent travel to or within Iran; a US citizen must join an official (i.e., Iranian government approved) tour group. Any activities outside those engaged-in by the group must be approved in advance by the tour operator, and on these activities the traveler must be accompanied by the leader assigned to the trip. A trip to Iran will be interesting and may be pretty, but it will not be unsupervised or extemporaneous.

Comment: @David good point, included in post now.

Comment: "Fees vary depending on your citizenship...": this question is about US citizens.

Comment: @phoog indeed, in this case the second part 'how urgently you need it' is probably more applicable, but I'll leave it in there to help anyone else.